# 20.04.1 errors while adding kernel modules

Tags: 20.04, kernel

I'm trying (don't really know what I'm doing) to add kernel modules atl1c (Atheros AR8151 ethernet) and ath9k (Atheros AR93xx Wifi) for two unclaimed network devices that have stopped working after the kernel update to 5.8.0.38.  My kernel was on 5.4.0.62 and both were working OK.

When I attempt to add the module with modprobe I get this:

```
$ sudo modprobe atl1c
modprobe: FATAL: Module ath1c not found in directory /lib/modules/5.8.0-38-generic
```

I have installed the 5.8.0-36 headers and modules!

Looking in the 5.8.0-36  modules directory I can see in the build area all the atheros net and wireless files are present and look the same as those in the 5.4.0-62 module build directory.

So I'm not sure if I am meant to do something else before issuing the modprobe command.

So is the modprobe all that should be needed or do I have do something else before?

Comment: This seems to be the same issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.8/+bug/1910675

Comment: Reported twelve days ago and no activity!!!  I added a comment!

Comment: When looking at the report again it is a little bit difficult to reproduce. No log files, no nothing to work on..

Comment: You can use grub-customizer to boot into the working 5.4 kernel until the issue is resolved. I have to do that with a different 5.8 problem. Looks like they are really on the heels regarding 20.04 kernel releases atm.